# MERN Stack app runs on local machine but fails on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku

I have been following MERN Stack front to back course by bradtraversy on udemy and I just finished building the project and it runs well on my local machine. But after running the build process using the heroku build script, my heroku CLI tells me that my build was successful. When I log into my heroku account I see the app in my dashboard but whenever I open it in my browser it will initially display the app before displaying a blank page. I do get the following error in my console but there seems to be nothing wrong with my code. My app can be found at https://arcane-cove-37667.herokuapp.com/ and below is the console error.

Console Error

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
arcane-cove-37667.herokuapp.com/:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
arcane-cove-37667.herokuapp.com/:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
arcane-cove-37667.herokuapp.com/:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
arcane-cove-37667.herokuapp.com/:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
arcane-cove-37667.herokuapp.com/:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
arcane-cove-37667.herokuapp.com/:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
react_devtools_backend.js:2574 TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at Experience.js:8
    at oi (react-dom.production.min.js:157)
    at Bu (react-dom.production.min.js:267)
    at Pl (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at Ol (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at xl (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at yl (react-dom.production.min.js:243)
    at react-dom.production.min.js:123
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.production.min.js:18)
    at Ho (react-dom.production.min.js:122)
overrideMethod @ react_devtools_backend.js:2574
uu @ react-dom.production.min.js:216
n.callback @ react-dom.production.min.js:216
da @ react-dom.production.min.js:131
hu @ react-dom.production.min.js:220
Ml @ react-dom.production.min.js:259
t.unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.production.min.js:18
Ho @ react-dom.production.min.js:122
Cl @ react-dom.production.min.js:252
yl @ react-dom.production.min.js:243
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:123
t.unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.production.min.js:18
Ho @ react-dom.production.min.js:122
Go @ react-dom.production.min.js:123
$o @ react-dom.production.min.js:122
vl @ react-dom.production.min.js:244
notify @ Subscription.js:19
t.notifyNestedSubs @ Subscription.js:90
t.handleChangeWrapper @ Subscription.js:95
v @ redux.js:296
dispatch @ VM203:3856
(anonymous) @ index.js:11
dispatch @ redux.js:659
(anonymous) @ profile.js:8
c @ runtime.js:63
(anonymous) @ runtime.js:293
(anonymous) @ runtime.js:118
r @ asyncToGenerator.js:3
u @ asyncToGenerator.js:25
Promise.then (async)
r @ asyncToGenerator.js:13
u @ asyncToGenerator.js:25
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:32
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:21
(anonymous) @ profile.js:5
(anonymous) @ index.js:8
dispatch @ VM203:14608
n.<computed> @ bindActionCreators.js:9
(anonymous) @ DashBoard.js:14
Rl @ react-dom.production.min.js:262
t.unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.production.min.js:18
Ho @ react-dom.production.min.js:122
Nl @ react-dom.production.min.js:261
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:261
Y @ scheduler.production.min.js:16
_.port1.onmessage @ scheduler.production.min.js:12
react_devtools_backend.js:2574 TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at Education.js:8
    at oi (react-dom.production.min.js:157)
    at Bu (react-dom.production.min.js:267)
    at Pl (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at Ol (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at xl (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at yl (react-dom.production.min.js:243)
    at react-dom.production.min.js:123
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.production.min.js:18)
    at Ho (react-dom.production.min.js:122)
overrideMethod @ react_devtools_backend.js:2574
uu @ react-dom.production.min.js:216
n.callback @ react-dom.production.min.js:216
da @ react-dom.production.min.js:131
hu @ react-dom.production.min.js:220
Ml @ react-dom.production.min.js:259
t.unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.production.min.js:18
Ho @ react-dom.production.min.js:122
Cl @ react-dom.production.min.js:252
yl @ react-dom.production.min.js:243
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:123
t.unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.production.min.js:18
Ho @ react-dom.production.min.js:122
Go @ react-dom.production.min.js:123
$o @ react-dom.production.min.js:122
vl @ react-dom.production.min.js:244
notify @ Subscription.js:19
t.notifyNestedSubs @ Subscription.js:90
t.handleChangeWrapper @ Subscription.js:95
v @ redux.js:296
dispatch @ VM203:3856
(anonymous) @ index.js:11
dispatch @ redux.js:659
(anonymous) @ profile.js:8
c @ runtime.js:63
(anonymous) @ runtime.js:293
(anonymous) @ runtime.js:118
r @ asyncToGenerator.js:3
u @ asyncToGenerator.js:25
Promise.then (async)
r @ asyncToGenerator.js:13
u @ asyncToGenerator.js:25
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:32
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:21
(anonymous) @ profile.js:5
(anonymous) @ index.js:8
dispatch @ VM203:14608
n.<computed> @ bindActionCreators.js:9
(anonymous) @ DashBoard.js:14
Rl @ react-dom.production.min.js:262
t.unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.production.min.js:18
Ho @ react-dom.production.min.js:122
Nl @ react-dom.production.min.js:261
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:261
Y @ scheduler.production.min.js:16
_.port1.onmessage @ scheduler.production.min.js:12
profile.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusText' of undefined
    at profile.js:16
    at c (runtime.js:63)
    at Generator._invoke (runtime.js:293)
    at Generator.next (runtime.js:118)
    at r (asyncToGenerator.js:3)
    at u (asyncToGenerator.js:25)
(anonymous) @ profile.js:16
c @ runtime.js:63
(anonymous) @ runtime.js:293
(anonymous) @ runtime.js:118
r @ asyncToGenerator.js:3
u @ asyncToGenerator.js:25
Promise.then (async)
r @ asyncToGenerator.js:13
u @ asyncToGenerator.js:25
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:32
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:21
(anonymous) @ profile.js:5
(anonymous) @ index.js:8
dispatch @ VM203:14608
n.<computed> @ bindActionCreators.js:9
(anonymous) @ DashBoard.js:14
Rl @ react-dom.production.min.js:262
t.unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.production.min.js:18
Ho @ react-dom.production.min.js:122
Nl @ react-dom.production.min.js:261
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:261
Y @ scheduler.production.min.js:16
_.port1.onmessage @ scheduler.production.min.js:12
```

I have checked the referenced code but I am yet to find anything wrong with it, please I really need help in solving this bug as it is giving me sleepless nights. My code for: the Education component, the Experience, the Dashboard.js and the profile.js reducer can be seen below.

Education.js

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Moment from 'react-moment';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { deleteEducation } from '../../actions/profile';

const Education = ({ education , deleteEducation }) => {
    const educations = education.map( edu => (
        <tr key={edu._id}>
            <td>{edu.school}</td>
            <td className="hide-sm">{edu.degree}</td>
            <td><Moment format="YYYY/MM/DD">{edu.from}</Moment> -{' '}
            {edu.to === null ? (' Now'): (<Moment format="YYYY/MM/DD">{edu.to}</Moment>)}
            </td>
            <td>
                <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => deleteEducation(edu._id)}>delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    ))
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <h2 className="my-2">Education Credentials</h2>
            <table className="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>School</th>
                        <th>Degree</th>
                        <th>Years</th>
                        <th />
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {educations}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

Education.propTypes = {
    education: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

export default connect(null, { deleteEducation })(Education);
```

Experience.js

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Moment from 'react-moment';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { deleteExperience } from '../../actions/profile';

const Experience = ({ experience, deleteExperience }) => {
    const experiences = experience.map( exp => (
        <tr key={exp._id}>
            <td>{exp.company}</td>
            <td className="hide-sm">{exp.title}</td>
            <td><Moment format="YYYY/MM/DD">{exp.from}</Moment> -{' '}
            {exp.to === null ? (' Now'): (<Moment format="YYYY/MM/DD">{exp.to}</Moment>)}
            </td>
            <td>
                <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => deleteExperience(exp._id)}>delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    ))
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <h2 className="my-2">Experience Credentials</h2>
            <table className="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Company</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Years</th>
                        <th />
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {experiences}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

Experience.propTypes = {
    experience: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

export default connect(null, { deleteExperience })(Experience);
```

Dashboard.js

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { getCurrentProfile } from '../../actions/profile'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Spinner from './Spinner';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import DashBoardActions from './DashBoardActions';
import Experience from './Experience';
import Education from './Education';
import { deleteAccount } from '../../actions/profile';

const DashBoard = ({ getCurrentProfile, deleteAccount, profile: {profile, loading}, auth: {user} }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        getCurrentProfile();
    }, [getCurrentProfile])
    return loading && profile === null ? (<Spinner />) : (<Fragment>
        <h1 className="large text-primary">Dashboard</h1>
        <p className="lead">
            <i className="fas fa-user"></i>Welcome {user && user.name}
        </p>
        {profile !== null ? (<Fragment>
            <DashBoardActions />
            <Experience experience={profile.experiences} />
            <Education education={profile.education} />
            <div className="my-2">
                <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => deleteAccount()}>
                    <i className="fas fa-user-minus"></i>{' '}
                    Delete My Account
                </button>
            </div>
        </Fragment>) : (<Fragment>
            <p>You have not yet setup a profile, please add some info</p>
            <Link to="/create-profile" className="btn btn-primary my-1">Create Profile</Link>

        </Fragment>)}
    </Fragment>)
}

DashBoard.propTypes = {
    getCurrentProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    profile: state.profile,
    auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getCurrentProfile, deleteAccount })(DashBoard);
```

profile.js reducer

```
import { GET_PROFILE, PROFILE_ERROR, CLEAR_PROFILE, UPDATE_PROFILE, GET_REPOS, GET_PROFILES } from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
    profile: null,
    profiles: [],
    repos: [],
    loading: true,
    error: {}
}

export default function(state=initialState, action) {
    const { type, payload } = action;

    switch(type) {
        case UPDATE_PROFILE:
        case GET_PROFILE:
            return {
                ...state,
                profile: payload,
                loading: false,
            }
        case GET_PROFILES:
            return {
                ...state,
                profiles: payload,
                loading: false
            }
        case PROFILE_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: payload,
                loading: false
            }
        case GET_REPOS:
            return {
                ...state,
                repos: payload,
                loading: false
            }
        case CLEAR_PROFILE:
            return {
                ...state,
                profile: null,
                repos: [],
                loading: false
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

If have any idea on how to solve this challenge please drop your comments.

Comment: Note that the [tag:git] tag usage text includes: "Also, do not use this tag for general programming questions that happen to involve a Git repository."

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use loading conditions in experience and education components. Otherwise, you can check experience and education array is empty or not before mapping. If experience is not empty then you map the array. Same for education array.